# what is the meaning of generating-sources in java building process

Tags: java, maven, build

I was reading the maven documentation, and i found that one of the build life cycle is the phase : generate-sources . So i am asking, what is the meaning of generatin-sources ? thnx

Comment: It's a step in the build process that generates source files from other files, e.g. generating Java source files from XML schema files (JAXB).

Comment: Generate Java Code from XSD, JSON, or for example MapStruct etc. anything which can generate source code ... that can of course also a plugin which you have written on your own.. depends on what you like to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Maven documentation:

> https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html
>
> The Modello plugin binds by default its goal modello:java to the
> generate-sources phase (Note: The modello:java goal generates Java
> source codes)

So if you happened to use a "model generator" (like [Modello](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/modello/))...

... and if you happened to use Maven (as opposed a different build tool, such as [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/))...

... then you'd use the Maven "generate-sources" phase to generate Java source code from your "model" file.

In most projects, you'll probably write your own source code, so you wouldn't need a "generate-sources" phase.

---

As Andreas noted above, another common use case for "generate-sources" is if your project needed to generate Java beans from [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) XML files: https://www.baeldung.com/jaxb.

I hope that answers your question :)